# How to run a program with highest privilege in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, administrator

I have a program (which communicates with a WiMax modem). The program runs fine with administrator account, but requires admin password to launch from standard user account. I'm using Windows 8 Pro.

I want standard users to run the program without requiring any password. From the properties of the executable file I've checked the box which states that "Run this program as administrator" for all users. But the program still asks for password if started from standard user account.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using task scheduler, create a task called "YourTask"(name it whatever you want). Under Security Options, tell it to run using your Admin account. If needed, check "Run with highest privileges". Do NOT check the "Do not store password"-box, since you want your password to be stored. In the action tab, create a new action for running your program. Leave the triggers empty. Save the task. Now create a shortcut on the user's desktop that runs this:

schtasks /Run /TN "YourTask"

Where YourTask is the name you gave to your task.